# Trouble with MLE

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, inference

I have a random sample $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$  with $X_i$ having a pdf

$$
f(x;\theta) = 2\theta^2x^{-2}
$$

I'd like to find the MLE of $\theta$.

First, because this is a random sample, all $X_i$ are iid. I proceed to find the joint pdf:

$$
f(\textbf{x}; \theta) = \prod{f(x_i; \theta)} = (2\theta^2)^n\prod{x_i^{-2}} = L(\theta; \textbf{x})
$$

Then log-likelihood:

$$
\ln(L) = n\ln(2\theta^2) -2\sum{\ln(x_i)} = n\ln(2) + 2n\ln(\theta) -2\sum{\ln(x_i)}
$$

Differentiate wrt $\theta$:

$$
\frac{\partial \ln(L)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{2n}{\theta}
$$

To find MLE, solve $\frac{\partial \ln(L)}{\partial \theta}  = 0$. However, the solution to this is that $\theta \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Warning: The density of $x$ is missing a constraint on the support as otherwise it does not integrate to one. This may explain for your difficulty.

Comment: To augment the comment by @Xi'an: The function you specify is not a valid pdf.  You can tell because its integral over all the real numbers diverges rather than equalling unity, as it must.